# How to make Xcode 14.2 run properly under rosetta after uninstalling Xcode 14.3?

Tags: xcode, macos-ventura, xcode14.3

After updating my macOS to Ventura, I decided to upgrade my Xcode to version 14.3. Later, I learned that our project would only run with Xcode 14.2, so I uninstalled 14.3 and reinstalled 14.2.

However, the project is no longer compiling under Rosetta (as it used to) with Xcode 14.2, and I'm receiving this error message:

`"Could not find module '' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator."`

I tried to delete `/Library/Developer` folder as well as `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`  ,and reinstall Xcode 14.2 (after deletion of 14.3).

I couldn't find much more info on problems after Xcode downgrade from 14.3 to 14.2. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After spending almost a day trying to fix this issue, I followed a suggestion made by [fssilva](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725563) in Apple Developer Forums, with one extra step:

- Removed the `/Library/Developer` folder
- Restarted my Mac (this step is extra)
- Downloaded and installed the Xcode Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.2
- Opened Xcode 14.2 and allowed it to install the remaining tools.

Comment: Opened Xcode 14.2 and allowed it to install the remaining tools.

HI @N.Cesarino, there are no remaining tools as such while opening Xcode . but still not working . I have upgraded macOS 13.1 to 13.4 .